# Unable to parse page text, getting "ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf.js

I am currently trying to create a util to parse annotations from a PDF. I can load the PDF file just fine, the annotation objects just fine, but I need to obtain the text that is related to those annotations (underlined, highlighted, etc.).

This gets hairy when I try to use the `getTextContent()` method which fails. Below is the method where this happens:

```
/**
 * @param pdf The PDF document obtained upon `pdfjs.getDocument(pdf).promise` success.
 */
function getAllPages(pdf) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let allPromises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < numPages; i++) {
      const pageNumber = i + 1; // note: pages are 1-based
      const page = pdf.getPage(pageNumber)
        .then((pageContent) => {

          // testing with just one page to see what's up
          if (pageNumber === 1) {
            try {
              pageContent.getTextContent()
                .then((txt) => {
                  // THIS NEVER OCCURS
                  console.log('got text');
                })
                .catch((error) => {
                  // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR SHOULD BE CAUGHT
                  console.error('in-promise error', error)
                });
            } catch (error) {
              // AT LEAST IT SHOULD BE CAUGHT HERE
              console.log('try/catch error:', error);
            }
          }
        })
        .catch(reject);

      allPromises.push(page);
    }
    Promise.all(allPromises)
      .then(() => {
        allPagesData.sort(sortByPageNumber);
        resolve(allPagesData);
      })
      .catch(reject);
  });
}
```

When calling `pageContent.getTextContent()`, which should return a promise, the error "`ReferenceError: ReadableStream is not defined`" is thrown in the `catch()` part of the `try`.

This is weird because I would have expected the `pageContent.getTextContent().catch()` to be able to, well, catch that. Also, I don't know what to do to resolve this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You are using Mozilla's pdfjs right? If yes then are you using `pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.js` file?

Comment: I am currently using `const pdfjs = require('pdfjs-dist');`, should I be requiring the one you mention instead?

Comment: Yes, give that one a try.

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: I am currently using Node v.12.13.1 (not married to it, just what I had running currently).

`const pdfjs = require('pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.js');`

This did the trick indeed, thanks @Shihab, no error thrown, text content now available!

Comment: @jansensan I am posting as an answer. I would appreciate your help ;)

Answer (score 6):

I have noticed that using `pdfjs-dist` causes the error.

Use `pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.js` instead.

```
const pdfjs = require('pdfjs-dist/es5/build/pdf.js');
```

**Update:**

```
const pdfJs = require('pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf')
```

[Example usage](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/364b9cc8028847a6123680a31de1cca8798d48e5/examples/node/pdf2png/pdf2png.js#L51)

Comment: Seems like they changed the right way to reference pdfjs some time ago (example code in project repo was changed in 2019/10 https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blame/364b9cc8028847a6123680a31de1cca8798d48e5/examples/node/pdf2png/pdf2png.js#L51 . That is a trap that many will stumble into, because any other code example I found in the web does it the old and wrong way.

Comment: I'm way late to the game, but does this mean pdf.js typescript nodejs support is completely borked?

Comment: This was changed again some time ago https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/commit/0068dba00966496ef41fc1a3454d1bb04d36c09d#comments, i dont know why, but i am not allowed to change the answer again:
keep looking to https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/node/pdf2png/pdf2png.js if pdf.js keeps changing

Answer (score 1):

There was a new change, the only way it worked here was to use this path:

```
const pdfJs = require('pdfjs-dist/legacy/build/pdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

I started a new project with pdfjs-dist and got the same ReadableStream error at getTextContent. Also i have an older project with the same lib that works fine. So, when I downgraded to an older version (2.0.943 to be precise) the error was gone. I don't realy know why. Hope that helps.